# How can I make a table column width somewhat similar automatically?

Tags: php, html, css

I wrote a PHP code to generate a table dynamically. The head of the table can be any text value in a database and the column of the table can be any text in the database.
If the value of the columns are the same or similar, then the width should be somewhat the same.

the following is my HTML code that is generated by PHP

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
    <table class="common2">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="12">Title</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left; width: 150px;">Answer Options</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">2</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">3</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">4</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">5</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">6</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">7</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">8</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">9</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">10</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">11+</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left; width: 150px;">Response Count</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">2</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

this is my common2 css code

```
.common2 
    {
        width: 100%;
        border: solid #E6E6E6 1px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        border-spacing: 0px;
        /* border-collapse: collapse; */
    }

    .common2 td 
    {
        padding: 6px;
        border: solid #E6E6E6 1px;
    }

    .common2 th 
    {
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        border: solid #E6E6E6 1px;
        background-color: #1A1A1C;
        padding: 8px;
        font-size: 14.5px;
    }

    .common2 th.highlighed
    {
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        border: 0px solid #DBDBDB;
        background-color: #666666;
        padding: 6px 10px;
    }   



.common2 tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;

}



.common tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

    .common2 tr:nth-child(even) 
    {
        background-color: #E8E8E8; /*#E7E9E8; /*#D6D8D7;*/
        position: relative;
    }



    .common2 td.stickOut
    {
        background-color: #DDEAFA; /*#DBAFAF;*/
        position: relative;
        font-weight: bold;
        border: solid #DBDBDB 1px;

    }



    .common2 td.head
    {
       background-color: #25328C; /* #4F4F4F; */
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #25328C;
        padding: 3px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 4px 10px;
        height: 35px;

        /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #2C3C92 0%, #25328C 100%);

        /* Mozilla Firefox */ 
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #2C3C92 0%, #25328C 100%);

        /* Opera */ 
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #2C3C92 0%, #25328C 100%);

        /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #2C3C92), color-stop(1, #25328C));

        /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #2C3C92 0%, #25328C 100%);

        /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #2C3C92 0%, #25328C 100%);

    }


    .common2 td.subfoot
    {
       background-color: #FFFF99; /* #4F4F4F; */
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
        padding: 3px;
        color: #000;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-style:italic;
        padding: 4px 10px;
    }



    .common2 td.foot1
    {
       background-color: #999999; /* #4F4F4F; */
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
        padding: 3px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 4px 10px;
    }

    .common2 td.foot2
    {
       background-color: #555555; /* #4F4F4F; */
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
        padding: 3px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 4px 10px;
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of my current output.

How can I make those columns with a similar width, excluding the very first column, as I specified how wide that will be?

[image]

Comment: Does `.common2 th {padding: 0; width: 8.33%;} .common2 td{padding: 0; width: 8.33%;}` solve your problems?

Comment: well since my table is dynamically created I don't know the count of the columns. That's why I can't use the width: 8.333%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove width property  from `.common2`

http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/knj9E/

Comment: That seems that it did it. Thanks